# Using URL Query to Set the Select List Value to Selected

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a page containing several select lists. After the user makes their selections and clicks a button I will add the selected options and values to the url to a different page containing the identical select lists.

I want to use the query to select the appropriate values on the new page by looping through the query and set the values of the corresponding select lists so that the lists on the new page mirror the page they just came from.

Here is a representative query string for testing;
    http://website.com/sign-up/?tf-from-country=Uruguay&tf-to-country=Canada

Here's 6 hours of research that fails but I don't know why.

```
    if ( window.location.search ) {
//console.log( window.location.search.substr(1).split('&') );

    var qs = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');

    for (var i=0; i< qs.length; i++){
        var param = qs[i].split('=');
        // console.log('setting field', param[0], 'to', param[1]);
        //$('.' + param[0]).addClass('foundit');
            // select list set to param
            var element = '.' + param[0];
            $(element).val(param[1]).attr("selected", true);
            //console.log(element);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the vars in the URL use the function:

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

this returns an associative array with all the variables.

Comment: Thanks but getting the data from the query string isn't the problem. Setting the values on the select lists is the problem.